# Unable to make font size responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying for an hour now and I am am unable to make the font size inside some columns(bootstrap). Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pm2nh/4/) that shows what's happening.

Is there any way that I can make that responsive?

Here's the CSS that I am using to make it responsive:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .digit {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
```

But it's not working. :/

Comment: It appears to me that your font size IS shrinking, but not scaling with the page size. Is that your end goal? To have the font size at 300px different than 400px?

Comment: 1em is always the same size unless the parent/body/root font-size is changed as well.

Comment: @EricHolmes I want it to shrink accordingly as the screen shrinks but it's acting weird. I want to fix that :'(

Comment: @Paulie_D The what should I do???? :;(

Comment: @EricHolmes The text is not in line and it's not shrinking accordingly. :/

Comment: "The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt." http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Thus your font-size for `.digit` will change to your current font-size (set in eg. `body`) when the screen is not greater than 450px. If you want it smaller you could change eg. `1em` to `0.5em` or change your current font-size in your media query.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Pm2nh/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a plugin for that : https://github.com/kagagnon/Responsive-Font

Once you include it, you must set your query point in JavaScript :

```
{
    queryPoint : font-size
}
```

For example :

```
rf('.digit').setQueryPoint({ //rf() = CSS selector.
    450 : 12,
    1500 : 40
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pm2nh/5/

Of course, you need to adjust the value for your needs.

Comment: Can you please bring all the text in that image? That was what I meant by "responsive". Please help.

Comment: Well, you just need to adjust your CSS, but right now it is too complicated for me to do it.

Comment: I don't think a plugin is necessary if OP takes advantage of `media-queries`(and `em`).

Comment: @BenZ. Sure he can, I may have misunderstood the question, but if he want to achieve what my plugin is doing, it would take way too much query points.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only worried about modern browsers (which most mobile browsers fall under) you can use the Viewport Width (vw) measurement. It's a percentage of the viewport's (Device's) width. Example with 3% width of the viewport. Resize the window and hit Run again.

http://jsfiddle.net/KA5qQ/

For more info, check our [Chris Coyier's blog post](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) on it.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myDiv {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```